# Understanding AUC curve

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, auc

[image]

In this image, I have a series of threshold as follows 0.5, 0.8, 0.85, 0.95. Now in this diagram, if I choose the threshold 0.8 because it has roughly 0.7 **True Positive Rate** and 0.2 **False Positive Rate** which is a better choice to someone who wants a higher TPR, then what would be my AUC?

Should I have to take the whole curve as AUC? Then what would be my threshold as my threshold starts from 0.5 and goes all the way till 0.95

Answer (score 1):

The AUC-ROC is defined across all the points shown in that graph. Please note that the threshold used to calculate any of the FPR/TPR rates shown is not directly depicted on that graph. Choosing the threshold should directly relate to misclassification costs. In the absence of them, we can use metrics like the [Youden Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic) or pick the threshold that maximise some other metric (e.g. the [$F_1$ score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) or the [Matthews correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient)) but that is not a best practice. ROC curves in a way, came to prominence especially because they are not reliant on a single threshold.

CV.SE has some interesting topics on the matter if you want to explore this further: [What are some common methods for choosing a discriminating threshold from an ROC curve?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278964/what-are-some-common-methods-for-choosing-a-discriminating-threshold-from-an-roc/278969#278969) and 
[Optimal classifier or optimal threshold for scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276867/optimal-classifier-or-optimal-threshold-for-scoring).

Comment: ok, so how will i get a AUC score given the above graph. i wanted to explain the audience in a better way that is the reason i mentioned 0.5, 0.8, 0.85, 0.95 threshold in the graph. my question is, what is the AUC score from the above

Comment: We can compute it using basic Geometry. We do not know the exact TPR & FPR values from looking at the attached graph alone.